# MVC model having only one JSON property

Tags: json, model-view-controller, model, properties

I am looking how to send regular MVC model to regular  MVC view with just one JSON string property inside the model.
I have the shirt model like

```
public class Shirt
{
[StringLength(120)]
public string Name { get; set; }

public string ShirtAvailbality { get; set; }
}
```

So, regular model,not a JsonResult and only the ShirtAvailbality string as JSON array of objects.
It should contain info for colors and sizes availability.

On the client I will have some JQuery / JavaScript code where I will disable the BUY button if a Color / Size combination is not available. For ex. blue shirt has all sizes available except XL.

The answer looks easy to me but I have never tried and I would like to see if I have some fundamental miss in my knowledges. Like is it possible ??
Thank you.

Tried to research but seems like very rare issue.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: The question is - is it possible and eventually ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is me again. Seems no one could answer. So, after few experiments I got to something working.

My Shirt model simplified

```
public class ShirtWithJasonStringVM
{

    public string ShirtName { get; set; }

    public string ShirtAvailablityJson { get; set; }
}
```

The C# model / object to be serialized

```
public class ShirtAvalabilityVM
{
    public int ShirtId { get; set; }

    public int ColorId { get; set; }

    public int SizeId { get; set; }

    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

The Action method which returns regular model to regular View

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult JsonTest()
{
 // model / object to be serialized
 ShirtAvalabilityVM shirtAvalabilityVM = new ShirtAvalabilityVM();
 shirtAvalabilityVM.ShirtId = 21;
 shirtAvalabilityVM.ColorId = 1;
 shirtAvalabilityVM.SizeId = 1;
 shirtAvalabilityVM.IsAvailable = true;

 ShirtWithJasonStringVM shirtWithJasonStringVM = new ShirtWithJasonStringVM();
 shirtWithJasonStringVM.ShirtName = "WhatEver";
 shirtWithJasonStringVM.ShirtAvailablityJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize<ShirtAvalabilityVM>(shirtAvalabilityVM);

  return View(shirtWithJasonStringVM);
}
```

The JsonTest view

```
@model GStore.Models.ViewModels.ShirtWithJasonStringVM

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "JsonTest";
 }

<h4>@Model.ShirtName</h4>

<script type="text/javascript">

    let tempVar = @Html.Raw(@Model.ShirtAvailablityJson);

    tempVar = JSON.stringify(tempVar)

    let someVar = JSON.parse(tempVar);

    console.log(someVar);

</script>
```

`@Html.Raw` was needed to get the string without encoding. `JSON.stringify` looks like redundant but it was needed to avoid JavaScript error.

It was:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse ()

This was the only cure I could find so far.

So in the console I could see the object. I will now keep experimenting to get list of `ShirtAvalabilityVM` and push them as array of objects to the JavaScript.

So still puzzled - is this approach correct, any fundamental problems ??? Thank you.

Addition: I found a way to Json stringify a list of `ShirtAvalabilityVM` on the controller's side.

Here is the code

```
shirtWithJasonStringVM.ShirtAvailablityJson =
JsonSerializer.Serialize<List<ShirtAvalabilityVM>>(listShirtAvalabilityVM);
```

I would consider mission accomplished. Only few thing observed. The string leaves the server's Action stringified but arrives into the JS code like parsed.

Looking backward that is why I had an error on `JSON.parse`.
May be `@Html.Raw` is making the parse.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).